# How can I add a clickable link to my collapsable sidebar menu without breaking my code?

Tags: html, css

Currently trying to make a sidebar on HTML/CSS however I am struggling to finalise it by adding clickable links for navigating around my site.

I believe it is a simple CSS issue or a simple HTML problem but it's driving me crazy!

```
<li class="c-menu__item has-submenu" title="Account">
    <div class="c-menu__item__inner"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
         <div class="c-menu-item__title">
             <a href="accountdetails.php"
                style="text-decoration: none"><span>Account Settings</span></div></a>
         </div>
```

Is what I have at the moment but there are two problems, I cannot click the button when the sidebar is collapsed, nor can I click the div the text/icon are present in, I must only click the text to get it to work.

Preferably I would like to click the box the icon, text are held in for easier usage.

How can I achieve this instead of just text being hyperlinked?

Photo showing the area I would like clickable on sidebar opposed to just the text

[image]

Comment: Your HTML is invalid for a start. You are closing a `div` tag inside the `a` tag that was opened outside of it.  Step one, fix your HTML\

Answer (score 2):

This is because your anchor tag is wrapping only the text "Account settings".
You should place your anchor tag in a way that wraps the elements that you want them to work like a link.

Also be aware that in the code you shared, you closed a div before closing the anchor tag, and you are not closing the list item tag.

Try like this:

```
<li class="c-menu__item has-submenu" title="Account" >
    <a href="accountdetails.php" style="text-decoration: none">
        <div class="c-menu__item__inner">
            <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
            <div class="c-menu-item__title">
                <span>Account Settings</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you closed `</div>` before `a` tag, But your `a` tag start just before your `span` tag.

Hence you need to close `a` tag before `</div>` like these:-

```
<li class="c-menu__item has-submenu" title="Account">
    <div class="c-menu__item__inner"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
         <div class="c-menu-item__title">
             <a href="accountdetails.php" style="text-decoration: none"> 
                  <span>Account Settings</span>
             </a>
         </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Now, you don't want to show that your text is hyperlinked, in that case, you can use `text-decoration: none;` to solve your issue.